# Controlling date/time format when using to_json

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I'm retrieving an entity from mongodb using the standard Ruby mongodb client, one of the fields of the object that I'm retrieving is of type 'Date' (mongo type) or 'Time' (Ruby type). I'm doing several manipulations on the retrieved object and lastly I'm transforming it to a json using to_json method.
The problem is that to_json decides to use a date format which is not good for me (e.g. "2013-02-13 14:08:39 UTC") and I don't find any way to control this format when calling to_json.
How can I control the format?
I have several 'Time' fields in this object so I looking for a solution that will cover all of them in one time.

Comment: Why does this format not work for you? Which format would you prefer, and why?

Comment: The actual reason is that I'm sending this date to a RESTful web service (written in Java but it doesn't really matter) and I get an exception since it fails to parse the date string, I need one of the standard formats like ISO 8601@spickermann

Comment: strftime does work but I'm looking for a wider solution, I don't want to traverse all the fields of my document and handle each one of them separately @Rubysmith

Answer (score 0):

Don't use '#to_json', but some means of more controlled serialization, e.g. https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers ;
handle date serialization for all fields where it is necessary in the serializer.

Comment: Thanks I'll have a look